# Apply JS if document url not a specific url

Tags: javascript, css, bigcommerce

I am helping a client do some minor Style/JS updates to a BigCommerce theme.  I know next to nothing about BigCommerce theming.  I need to apply CSS to every page except the home page.  Ordinarily do page specific JS or scope my CSS better, but in this case I am limited by the existing theme code.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var check_url = 'http://www.someurl.com'
if (document.url != check_url) {
   $('.header').css('height', '32vh');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Seems like a very simple concept.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.pathname != '/') {
   $('.header').css('height', '32vh');
}
```

Worked!